# what wrong with non object oriented approach to introduce object oriented approach

Tags: java, c, oop, object-oriented-analysis

i have been reading about this topic , and the more i read the more confused i get ,

can somebody please elaborate , we were using language C which follows structural approach ,
so what was wrong with this approach , that we moved to create a object oriented language JAVA .

I have been reading so many theoretical aspects , can some body please give more of a few practical illustrations , 
WHY WE NEEDED OBJECT ORIENTED APPROACH IN THE FIRST PLACE

I am not looking for an answer to be given in any interview or tutorial
I am looking for an answer to get the better understanding/practical importance of object oriented aproach

Comment: This question is far too broad and can't really be answered objectively. It depends on the programmer's preferences.

Comment: i don't think so - there are objective reasons for OO (pun unintended)

Comment: An Object Oriented approach helps modularize things.

Comment: i was in the middle of composing an answer, if you edit the question, i'll have a chance to post it.

Comment: the problem with such aggressive closing is that hasty answers remain, but thoughtful answers get locked out.

Comment: @randomstring : i tried reopening , is it available to you now ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid: you need 4 more reopen votes for this to actually happen. I don't see that happening.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid nope, i thought editing the question would automatically reopen it. i will get you an answer one way or the other within an hour or two. i think right now they are aggressively watching the question to make sure it is not answered. in a few minutes they will cool off.

Comment: @randomstring : if its not available to you here , can you please fill me in at hussain1585@gmail.com

Comment: and it's a nicely asked question -- you already have 4 upvotes :D

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid: you could also ask: _Why do we need C? Assembler worked just fine._ It's just another level of abstraction. It's a good choice for certain problems and a bad choice for others.

Comment: @randomstring : 4 downvotes as well , lol , i hope i can afford those many downvotes to get the decent answer :) :) :)

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid here is the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372608/how-to-avoid-passing-arguments-repeatedly i will post others when i am bored (which should be soon ;-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many explanations regarding this. But I would like to refer [this](http://www.ctp.bilkent.edu.tr/~russell/java/LectureNotes/1_OOConcepts.htm)

> 1. **Modularity**: The source code for a class can be written and maintained independently of the source code for other classes. Once
>      created, an object can be easily passed around inside the system.
> 2. **Information-hiding:** By interacting only with an object's methods, the details of its internal implementation remain hidden from
>      the outside world.
> 3. **Code re-use:** If a class already exists, you can use objects from that class in your program. This allows programmers to
>      implement/test/debug complex, task-specific objects, which you can
>      then use in your own code.
> 4. **Easy Debugging:** If a particular object turns out to be a problem, you can simply remove it from your application and plug in a
>      different object as its replacement. This is analogous to fixing
>      mechanical problems in the real world. If a bolt breaks, you replace
>      it, not the entire machine.

Comment: Copied because I think they wrote it its written in a better way than I would